# How to fairly divide commercial real estate earnings amongst multiple property owners?

Tags: real-estate

I'm exaggerating to make things obvious:

Say you have 2 adjacent commercial properties. One is a decrepit tear down (FMV 100K) The other is a vibrant professional retail space, as good as it gets (FMV 900k) Same size properties.
Both owners decide to sell the land together to some developer. 1 Million for both properties. Does each property owner get 500K? Or, does property A get 90% and property B get 10%?
Wouldn't property B fellow argue that the sale is for land only (the assumption that the developer is going to knock them down anyways - maybe).
Whats the fairest protocol? (in my situation there will be 5-7 owners deciding to sell together.
Do we appraise each property (building + land) and have that determine our proportionate share of the sale price? Or just land square footage divided into the sale price?

My first post! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is something the owners have to work out between them. There is no one size fits all answer; in every case the amount of money/effort/time invested is divided differently and the parties involved have to reach an agreement on whether and how to value these when dividing the income.

Answer (score 2):

This scenario doesn't really make sense. Why are the two properties being sold together? If they were sold separately then there would be a price for each and you would know how much each owner gets.

In that scenario though, the only real answer is that the proceeds should be divided in whatever way the owners think is fair - unless there was a previous agreement, in which case you divide it according to the agreement.

A relatively simple way of doing the division is to get both properties evaluated and divide the sale income in proportion to that.

Answer (score 1):

Property sales would be individual contracts between the current owners and the property developer.  The owner of property A would expect to be given the full market value of their property, and they have no reason to give any of that money to the owner of property B.

In some cases the owner of the last property to sell will end up with more money, as the developer is desperate to finish buying up the whole block.  The developer may have to offer extra money to the last owner to get them to sell.